# React custom synthetic event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a custom synthetic event so that I can conditionally attach a handler (either a touchstart or click), based on a configuration option
However, I cannot seem to find any information on how this can be done
Ideally I would like the below (the onTap attribute)

```
<Button onTap={someHandler} title="Register" />
```

And then the onTap would attach the handler either on touchstart or click or any event I define in a config

Is this possible?
Is it possible to define a custom attribute that will hook on every component?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
const W = (() => {
  // all elements supported by React
  const names = 'a|abbr|address|area|article|aside|audio|b|base|bdi|bdo|big|blockquote|body|br|button|canvas|caption|cite|code|col|colgroup|data|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dialog|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|footer|form|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|head|header|hgroup|hr|html|i|iframe|img|input|ins|kbd|keygen|label|legend|li|link|main|map|mark|menu|menuitem|meta|meter|nav|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|option|output|p|param|picture|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|ruby|s|samp|script|section|select|small|source|span|strong|style|sub|summary|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|time|title|tr|track|u|ul|var|video|wbr|circle|clipPath|defs|ellipse|g|image|line|linearGradient|mask|path|pattern|polygon|polyline|radialGradient|rect|stop|svg|text|tspan'.split('|')
  const res = {}
  for (const El of names) {
    res[El] = ({ onTap, ...props }) => {
      onTap = onTap || x=>x
      props.onClick = props.onClick || x => x
      props.onTouchStart = props.onTouchStart || x => x
      <El {...props} onClick={(...args) => {onTap(...args); props.onClick(...args)} onTouchStart={(...args) => {onTap(...args); props.onTouchStart(...args)} />
    }
  }
  return res;
})()

<W.button onTap={() => alert('hi')} />
```

This will add the onTap handler to both the `onClick` and `onTouchStart` events of any element.

A similar technique can be used to wrap composite components.

---

To wrap **every** component, you need to wrap `React.createElement`.

> **Warning**: I make no guarantees about if this will work. It is probably a very bad idea, and should **not** be used in a library.

```
const _ce = React.createElement.bind(React)
React.createElement = (name, props, ...args) => {
  if (!props) {
    return _ce(name, props, ...args)
  }
  const { onTap, ...newProps } = props
  if (onTap) {
    if (props.onClick) {
        newProps.onClick = (...args) => {
          props.onClick(...args)
          onTap(...args)
        }
    } else {
      newProps.onClick = onTap
    }
    if (props.onTouchStart) {
        newProps.onTouchStart = (...args) => {
          props.onTouchStart(...args)
          onTap(...args)
        }
    } else {
      newProps.onTouchStart = onTap
    }
  }
  return _ce(name, newProps, ...args)
}
```

Comment: Hi. I need it for all components not just the button. The button was mentioned just for showing the requirement

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was hoping however something  more clean, ie no wrapping of all elements. I suppose this is not possible.

Comment: @Thomas See edit — It’s not that clean, but you don’t need to wrap all of the elements.

Comment: Excellent idea. Tried it this way and works fine. Plus, it is way cleaner. Thanks a lot